# Google App Engine - Python 2.7 - 'Persistent memory' issues?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

The title is likely not the correct wording for my issue, but I'm still very new to programming, and especially new to web development and the like.

In a normal python environment a reference to a variable doesn't effect the original object. So:

```
x = 1
y = x
y += 1
print x,y
>>> 1, 2
```

Likewise, if I do ...

```
x = [[1,2], [3,4]]
y = x[0]
z = y[0] + 1
print x
>>> [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

However, in Google App Engine if I do the above example I instead get:

```
print x
>>> [[2, 2], [3, 4]]
```

So, my question is this.  WTF?

I have a list similar to `x`, but much larger, that I access (without modifying) and build other lists using that data. When I then change the contents of the new lists it ALSO changes what's in the original list. So when I refresh the webpage I expect to get similar results as when it first loaded but instead the original list is completely changed. Every refresh after that just makes it worse and worse. Now, I've spent HOURS going through all my code, line by line, and I'm now convinced that it isn't my code. So, does GAE work differently than I am expecting? Is this normal behavior? And more importantly, how on earth do I fix it (get it to work like a normal python interpreter)?

EDIT:

Ok, so I just confirmed. I have a global immutable constant called `SKILLS`. I then do `all_skills = SKILLS`. Later on I loop through `all_skills` and pull out 10 random skills (SKILLS is a tuple containing lists that represent the skills for the game) and assign them to a class instance variable. I then confirmed that SKILLS was unmodified, then modified the class variables, and when I rechecked SKILLS all the skills that were changed in the class variable were also changed in SKILLS, which should not be possible unless I am COMPLETELY misunderstanding something.

If you're extra curious you can check out the two modules in question https://github.com/jtsmith1287/gurpscg/blob/master/charbuilder.py and https://github.com/jtsmith1287/gurpscg/blob/master/skills.py
and if you'd like to see what the app does just load http://gurpscgtest.appspot.com and refresh it a few times and look at the table.

Comment: You have too much code for us to wade through looking for a bug.  Somewhere you will be modifying SKILLS.  This would be such a fundamental error in the appengine runtime that it would have been noticed before now.  For skills to be modifed in module SKILLS it means you are just referencing the skill in the TUPLE not making a copy.

Comment: @TimHoffman I ran all_skills = SKILLS[:], then ran id() on both and they returned the same address. The documentation says this is how to make a copy of a list. It's not working (at least not how I understand it should be).

Comment: Disregard. I went deeper and made sure I was making copies of each individual list as they were modified and this solved the error. If you'd like to post an answer I'll submit it as correct. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing this in the development server, or when deployed? If the former, then I'm really surprised -- we don't do anything that changes the core semantics of Python.

If you're seeing this when deployed to appspot.com, then is is possible that you're changing a global variable and expecting that change to be visible across requests? If that's the case, there's an easy, though possibly non-obvious explanation: Sequential requests aren't guaranteed to be serviced by the same instance of the application. That's one of App Engine's features: Increases in the rate of incoming requests causes more instances to be started, so that the increase in load can be spread out. (This'll happen slower if you have multi-threading enabled.)

What this boils down to is that the GAE environment, global are mostly useful as a cache of immutable values.

Comment: I'm seeing this in both, actually. And no, I'm changing a class variable created from accessing multiple global variables. When I then modify these class variables it seems to also be modifying the global. You said "immutable" and I then sprinted to my IDE, changed the global to a tuple instead of a list hoping it would prevent any changes... but alas it didn't do anything. I'm stumped. I just don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Not happened in my local dev_appserver, I'm using appengine 1.7.5. It might be something else in your code causing this behavior

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        x = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
        y = x[0]
        z = y[0] + 1
        print x , y , z

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
    [
     ('/', MainPage)],
    debug=True)
```

Result

[[1, 2], [3, 4]] [1, 2] 2 Status: 200 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Content-Length: 0 Cache-Control: no-cache

Comment: I'm using version 1.8.3.

Comment: I get same result in 1.8.3 [[1, 2], [3, 4]] [1, 2] 2. I'm guessing the element that you changed is still just a reference to the element in the SKILLS tuple, hence when you changed it, it also changed the entry in the tuple. You can double check this using the id() function before you change one of the skill element to check whether they're pointing to the same list or not